# How can I map multiple data of object?

Tags: jquery, object, join

This...

```
return (data.map(obj => obj.name)).join('<br>');
```

...gives me the output:

```
monkey
cat
snake
elephant
```

And this..

```
return (data.map(obj => obj.group.id)).join('<br>');
```

... gives me the output:

```
2
4
6
3
```

The output I need is:

```
id: 2, name: monkey
id: 4, name: cat
id: 6, name: snake
id: 3, name: elephant
```

This is my approach:

```
return ('id:' + data.map(obj => obj.group.id) + ', name: 'data.map(obj => obj.name)).join('<br>');
```

The error:

> SyntaxError: missing ) in parenthetical

Comment: can you provide your  `data` array?

Comment: You can do as 
(data.map(obj => 'id: ' + obj.id + ', name: ' + obj.name)).join('<br>')

Comment: Return the combined final string for each obj in a single `.map` rather than call .map multiple times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close! Use [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make the job a lot easier.

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: "monkey",
        group: {
            id: "2"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "cat",
        group: {
            id: "4"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "snake",
        group: {
            id: "6"
        }
    },
    {
        name: "elephant",
        group: {
            id: "3"
        }
    }
];

const joined = data.map(obj => `id: ${obj.group.id}, name: ${obj.name}`).join('<br>');

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = joined;
```

```html
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: How great! Thank you very much